# Is there a way to enable raw mouse input?

Tags: mouse

Is there a way to enable raw mouse input on ubuntu? The equivalent to windows on notch 6/11, with increase point precision disabled. I tried ubuntu once and the mouse felt really weird, and way to fast even on lowest sensitivity.